# zk textbox value empty on drag and drop

Tags: textbox, drag, zk

i have two textbox:

and

when i made drag and drop from second textbox to first textbox i see on the screen the value but when i save the page, the first textbox value is empty.

In another jsp everything work.
Difference between the two jsp: the second one made a submitForm instead the first call a procedure that read data (using composer) in java and post the data manually (no SubmitForm)

the problem i think is in this difference but i don't know how to manage the first call described below (i cannot use SubmitForm)

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a ZKFiddle for your problem (as I understood):

http://zkfiddle.org/sample/22qriko/1-zk-textbox-value-empty-on-drag-and-drop

It's seems to be a ZK issue with onChanging event and the drag&drop in a textbox.

As you can see in the zkfiddle, the onChanging event is not call after a drag& drop as we could expect.

If you can, try to use onChange event (it is fired when the input lose focus), when you click on the Button in the zkfiddle, the value is correctly set in the Textbox component.

You can use the bug tracker to submit this issue :

http://tracker.zkoss.org/secure/IssueNavigator.jspa

Comment: yes, this is exaclty my problem. I have create a issue on bug tracker now. thank you